# Select from createListBox with ScriptDb

Tags: google-apps-script

I have this code in input:

```
 utentiGrid.setWidget(1, 2, app.createLabel('Stato:'));
 utentiGrid.setWidget(1, 3,
 app.createListBox().setName('tipologia').addItem("Alpha").addItem("Beta"));
```

I select "Beta" and write ScriptDb

Then I take the record and  visualize the result by modifying with this code:

```
utentiGrid.setWidget(1, 2, app.createLabel('Stato:'));
utentiGrid.setWidget(1, 3,
app.createListBox().setName('tipologia').addItem("Alpha").addItem("Beta"));
```

The problem 
I want see my first selection ("Beta") and not "Alpha".
how can I do?

thank you

raffaele

p.s. are not a programmer but scriptDb is fantastic!

Comment: You say `scriptDb` in the title and in the question, and mention it in your comment to @br_araujo's answer, but you don't show any in your code. Don't make us guess about what you mean; edit your question to show it.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the method setSelectedItem as bellow:

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var utentiGrid = app.createGrid(3, 4);

  utentiGrid.setWidget(1, 2, app.createLabel('Stato:'));
  var listBox = app.createListBox().setName('tipologia').addItem("Alpha").addItem("Beta");

  //To select Beta use 1 as argument
  listBox.setItemSelected(1, true);

  utentiGrid.setWidget(1, 3, listBox);


  app.add(utentiGrid);
  return app;
}
```

If you change the argument to 0 the item selected will be alpha. If you have a third element, their index will be 2 and so one.

Comment: br araujo thanks for the answer but maybe I explained evil.
Let me explain.
In the update, when I read the databse I have to display the data stored in the database (Alpha or Beta or other) and then be able to confirm or select another option.